# Shouldn’t GridView’s RowStyle-HorizontalAlign property overwrite CSS’s text-align property?

Tags: .net, asp.net, css

a) As far as I know, `GridView’s RowStyle-HorizontalAlign` property should overwrite CSS’s `text-align` property, and thus text inside GridView's cells should be located on the left side of the cells, but is instead moved to the right side. Why is that?

b) Similarly, `RowStyle-Font-Bold` should overwrite CSS’s `font-weight` property and thus fonts shouldn’t be in bold. But again, CSS’s property overwrites `RowStyle’s Font-Bold` property. Why?

```
<div id="someClass">            
      <asp:GridView ID="gvwShowUsers"  runat="server" >
          <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Bold="false" 
               HorizontalAlign="Left" />
          <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName"  />
          </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

CSS file:

```
#someClass td
{
  font-weight:bolder;
  text-align:right;
}
```

thanx

EDIT:

> A workaround would be to apply the style to each field instead (e.g. ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign)

I tried with applying `ItemStyle` to `GridView’s` field:

```
   <div id="someClass">            
      <asp:GridView ID="gvwShowUsers"  runat="server" >
         <RowStyle Font-Bold="false" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
          <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Bold="false" />
             </asp:BoundField>
          </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
   </div>
```

But since even after applying `ItemStyle` the page still displayed text on the right side of the cells, I've decided to check the source code of a html page sent to the user, and as it turns out both `<tr>` and `<td>` elements have `Align` property set to `left`, so...totally confused!

Here is the source code of a html page:

```
<table id="GridView1" style="font-weight:normal;">
   <tr align="center" style=" font-weight:bold;">
       <th scope="col">UserName</th>
   </tr>
       <tr align="right" valign="bottom" style="font-weight:normal;">
       <td align="right" style="font-weight:normal;"> Nancy</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works for me - create a style, e.g. td.left{text-align:left;} and reference it in the bound field's itemstyle, like so <ItemStyle CssClass="left"></ItemStyle>

Answer (score 1):

If the style is being added to the `<tr>` element, the style in the CSS file will win because the `#someClass td` selector is more specific.

A workaround would be to apply the style to each field instead (e.g. `ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign`).

Comment: "If the style is being added to the <tr> element, the style in the CSS file will win because the #someClass td selector is more specific." Don't inline styles styles always win ( I'm assuming GridView.RowStyle-HorizontalAlign is inline style? )?
"A workaround would be to apply the style to each field instead (e.g. ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign)." I did try that, but to no effect

Comment: To paraphrase Jerry MacGuire, show me the HTML :). 

Inline styles win when applied to the *same element* as a CSS rule, but not when they are applied to a parent element. Just because you've made your text red in your body tag's style attribute, doesn't mean you can't have a green paragraph specified with a CSS rule.

Comment: hi,I've edited my initial post in a response to your reply...in case you are willing to help me some more